# Get tags like Stackoverflow with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

My model is like this:

```
Flavor
  public IList<Mention> Mentions

Mention
  public IList<Flavor> Flavors
```

Therefore, a many-to-many between Flavor and Mention.

I need to create a query that returns me the flavors mentioned and the amount of times it was mentioned.

Today, I can get the query terms ordered by the number of flavors mentioned but can not return the whole lot of times.

My hql query:

```
  select flavor
  from Flavor flavor
  left join flavor.Mention mentions
  group by flavor.Id, flavor.Name
  order by count(mentions) desc
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var flavors = Session.CreateQuery(@"select f.Id, f.PropertyName, count(elements(f.Mentions)) 
                                   from Flavor f where exists elements(f.Mentions) group by f.Id, f.PropertyName").List();
```

I believe it does the trick...

Comment: I try, but how can get count(elements(f.Mentions))? 

I can create one property in Flavor, per example, NumberOfMentions. How auto add count(elements(f.Mentions)) in NumberOfMentions ?

Thank´s

Comment: The code only assumes that your mappings are as you have them (Flavor has a many-to-many property called: Mentions and Mention has a many-to-many property called: Flavors. That's it. You do not need to create any extra properties.

Comment: I could not yet. I think I'll have to change my strategy.
In addition to obtaining the top flavor, must be of "mentions" of specific type. (e.g: Mention.Type = TypeMention.Question).

I must also order the amount of Flavor.

Complicated?

Comment: Considering your new requirements try to break the query into 2 queries or more... I believe it gets very complicated if you try to squeeze everything in one query.